# Make email body content parts visible only to specific BCC recipient

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I am looking if this is possible in Outlook/office365; or generally to do something like this while sending email

> Team,
>   we are doing bad job at X {@John: Adam is screwing this every time. Don't reply to this - you're BCC}
>   we need to improve

I want to insert content that will be visible only to specific user, in this case John.

Comment: Send a separate email. What happens if you mess it up? Now Adam knows you are complaining about him to John.

Comment: Outlook doesn't provide a feature like this. I doubt there is a way to achieve this in Outlook/Office 365. Why not just send two separate messages like the others suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email doesn't work like that.

While it may be possible to write code that MIGHT have that affect, only setting the text to visible if certain criteria are met, the important thing to note is that Adam's email client will receive the exact same email and it would be trivial for Adam to see that "hidden" message.

No, if you wish to send a message in an email that one person WILL NOT SEE, the only correct way to do that is to NOT send the message to that one person.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of Outlook. If it has some tool that can do it. Because message could have encrypted parts in its body and lets say, only if viewed on John's client box, it could be read. then again, this is just theory.

Comment: Huh.. How did I not see your answer before I commented?

Comment: @T.S.: Even if it couldn't be _decrypted_ by normal recipients, it would still reveal to them that there are some other hidden recipients, and I think it'd be confusing even for this BCC to see such a message. (For that matter, BCC is often confusing in general. I would echo the recommendation I've seen of sending the original message _only_ to Adam, then _forwarding_ it John with your commentary added.)

Comment: @grawity with my boss, 2 emails is only solution. He starts to reply all like crazy

Answer (score -1):

An email client can be programmed to do this capability by sending only the text intended for a recipient to that recipient while text not intended for that recipient will not be sent.  This can make it more convenient for users to securely hide certain texts from selected recipients as the hidden texts are actually not sent to the unintended recipients, and therefore, they have no way to view them. It is important for the email client to provide a friendly interface to capture instructions as to what texts are intended for which recipients.  Otherwise, users may find the capability useless as it is tedious to provide such instructions.

Comment: I see that you've spent some time to type it. Thanks. But the question was about Outlook/office365. Your answer is very generic. For example: "An email client can be programmed to do this capability" - what client? A special application I need to distribute to users? Not clear

Comment: This doesn't seem like a genuine answer at all. Is it a copy paste from a paper listing generally desirable features of e-mail client software?